# discord.py trying to save individual data but getting json decode error

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm making a bot in discord.py, I'm trying to save individual information for each user.
I'm a bit new to python and new to discord.py, so sorry if this is a bad way of doing this.
I also don't use the json library for python all that much, so I'm not very familiar with it.
And yes, I have a file called users.json in the botfolder directory.

Here's my code:

```
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------------------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('/home/ian/python/botfolder/users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_cash(users, message.author)
 
    with open('/home/ian/python/botfolder/users.json', 'w') as f:
         json.dump(users, f, indent=3)
    
    await client.process_commands(message)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if f'{user.id}' in users:
        return
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]['money'] = 0

client.run('token')
```

And here's the error (I'm on unbuntu by the way)

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ian/python/botfolder/counrtybot2.py", line 18, in on_message
    users = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I've never seen a JSONDecodeError, but it is possible I've installed something wrong.
The error appears every time anyone sends a message.

Comment: add {} in JSON file and sav

Comment: Is the file empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the file. You should catch the error and handle it when it’s empty, or maybe never let there be an empty file. Make it so the the file is only created with json in it, or it’s not created.

Answer (score 0):

The awnser it's simple just add :

```
{

}
```

You need to put that because if not, the code will know that the file exist, but could not read it or edit it.

Comment: Could you provide a full code snippet? This would help your answer by improving the quality.